# How can laravel use the data from angular ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, laravel-4

This is in my angular app. I try to send this data to laravel.

```
$scope.add = function(){
    if($scope.new_brand.trim() !=='') $scope.brands.push({name:$scope.new_brand});

    $http.post('brand', {'name':$scope.new_brand})
    .success(function(data) {

    });

    $scope.new_brand='';


}
```

and this is what I try to do in controller.

```
public function store()
{
    $brand       = new Brand;
    $brand->name = /**what should behere**/ ;
            $brand->save();
}
```

I don't know how to use the data from the view. thx in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Input::get('name') like this

```
public function store()
{
    $brand       = new Brand;
    $brand->name = Input::get('name');
    $brand->save();
}
```

Off course I assume that you have properly created your routes and that your controller its not namespaced. If it is you can use either \Input::get('name') or `use Input;`

Check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input) for more info.

**EDIT**

I don't know how your HTML is set up so here is a basic example that works fine for me:

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app>

<body ng-controller="BrandsController">

<form ng-submit="add()">

  <input type="name" id="name" ng-model="newBrand"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function BrandsController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.add = function() {

            $http.post('brand', {'name':$scope.newBrand})

            .success(function(data) {console.log(data)});

        }
    }

</script>

</html>
```

**LARAVEL ROUTE**

```
Route::resource('brand', 'BrandsController');
```

**BRANDS CONTROLLER**

```
class BrandsController extends \BaseController {

  // Other functions

  public function store()
  {
    return Response::json(array('name' =>Input::get('name')));
  }

}
```

Comment: Is that correct that I use post method for store in resource controller. it return 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: Yes it is. How is your route defined?

Comment: Route::resource('brand', 'BrandController');

Comment: And if i use get it still can return the view.

Comment: I don't get it. Your example works really well without any error but it occur twice. And with 500 Internal server error, the data is stored but it store twice.

Comment: You should post your full code, like i did in the example, in order to be able to check it.

Comment: I found the cause now. I import angular twice. thx for your help :D

Comment: @tliokos you rock, after an hour of searching your solution worked for me :)